# Django_googleapi_project: AttributeError at /profile Exception Value: 'User' object has no attribute 'userprofile'

Tags: python, django, profile

I have been following this video to learn django: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_vCT42vDfgw .

I have followed to the end, have run the server at `localhost port 8000`. I can signup users but when I try to update a user profile (clicking the `'Update User Profile'` link in the view, I get an `'AttributeError at/profile'` which I have not been able to resolve despite checking in with the tutor's source code (everything looks the same) looking up answers to similar questions on stack overflow here.
Any help would be much appreciated...

Here' the error test:

```
Environment:

Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/profile

Django Version: 3.2.9
Python Version: 3.10.0
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'main',
 'users']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Toshiba\Envs\django_googleapi_project\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\Toshiba\Envs\django_googleapi_project\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "c:\django_googleapi_project\users\views.py", line 48, in profile_view
    up = user.userprofile
  File "C:\Users\Toshiba\Envs\django_googleapi_project\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 247, in inner
    return func(self._wrapped, *args)

Exception Type: AttributeError at /profile
Exception Value: 'User' object has no attribute 'userprofile'
```

Here's the code sample in  the users\views.py file that contains the 'userprofile' object:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, reverse
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth import login, logout, authenticate
from django.conf import settings
from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.views.generic.edit import FormView
from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator


from django_googleapi_project.mixins import(
    AjaxFormMixin, 
    reCAPTCHAValidation,
    FormErrors,
    RedirectParams,
    )


from .forms import (
    UserForm,
    UserProfileForm,
    AuthForm,
    )

result = "Error"
message = "There was an error, please try again"


class AccountView(TemplateView):
    '''
    Generic FormView with our mixin to display user account page
    '''
    template_name = "users/account.html"

    @method_decorator(login_required)
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().dispatch(*args, **kwargs)



#@login_required
def profile_view(request):
    '''
    function view to allow users to update their profile
    '''
    user = request.user
    up = user.userprofile

    form = UserProfileForm(instance = up) 

    if request.is_ajax():
        form = UserProfileForm(data = request.POST, instance = up)
        if form.is_valid():
            obj = form.save()
            obj.has_profile = True
            obj.save()
            result = "Success"
            message = "Your profile has been updated"
        else:
            message = FormErrors(form)
        data = {'result': result, 'message': message}
        return JsonResponse(data)

    else:

        context = {'form': form}
        context['google_api_key'] = settings.GOOGLE_API_KEY
        context['base_country'] = settings.BASE_COUNTRY

        return render(request, 'users/profile.html', context)



class SignUpView(AjaxFormMixin, FormView):
    '''
    Generic FormView with our mixin for user sign-up with reCAPTURE security
    '''

    template_name = "users/sign_up.html"
    form_class = UserForm
    success_url = "/"

    #reCAPTURE key required in context
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context["recaptcha_site_key"] = settings.RECAPTCHA_PUBLIC_KEY
        return context

    #over write the mixin logic to get, check and save reCAPTURE score
    def form_valid(self, form):
        response = super(AjaxFormMixin, self).form_valid(form)  
        if self.request.is_ajax():
            token = form.cleaned_data.get('token')
            captcha = reCAPTCHAValidation(token)
            if captcha["success"]:
                obj = form.save()
                obj.email = obj.username
                obj.save()
                up = obj.userprofile
                up.captcha_score = float(captcha["score"])
                up.save()
                
                login(self.request, obj, backend='django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend')

                #change result & message on success
                result = "Success"
                message = "Thank you for signing up"

                
            data = {'result': result, 'message': message}
            return JsonResponse(data)

        return response




class SignInView(AjaxFormMixin, FormView):
    '''
    Generic FormView with our mixin for user sign-in
    '''

    template_name = "users/sign_in.html"
    form_class = AuthForm
    success_url = "/"

    def form_valid(self, form):
        response = super(AjaxFormMixin, self).form_valid(form)  
        if self.request.is_ajax():
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')
            #attempt to authenticate user
            user = authenticate(self.request, username=username, password=password)
            if user is not None:
                login(self.request, user, backend='django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend')
                result = "Success"
                message = 'You are now logged in'
            else:
                message = FormErrors(form)
            data = {'result': result, 'message': message}
            return JsonResponse(data)
        return response




def sign_out(request):
    '''
    Basic view for user sign out
    '''
    logout(request)
    return redirect(reverse('users:sign-in'))
```

Here's the users.models file; I have a class 'UserProfile'. I have tried changing this to 'userprofile' but the error persists. Maybe I haven't done the right imports?

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User



class UserProfile(models.Model):
    '''
    Our UserProfile model extends the built-in Django User Model
    '''
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='profile', on_delete = models.CASCADE)

    address = models.CharField(verbose_name = "Address", max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    town = models.CharField(verbose_name = "Town/City", max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    county = models.CharField(verbose_name = "County", max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    post_code = models.CharField(verbose_name = "Post Code", max_length=8, null=True, blank=True)
    country = models.CharField(verbose_name = "Country", max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    longitude = models.CharField(verbose_name = "Longitude", max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    latitude = models.CharField(verbose_name = "Latitude", max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)

    captcha_score = models.FloatField(default = 0.0)
    has_profile = models.BooleanField(default = False)

    is_active = models.BooleanField(default = True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user}'
```

Comment: show models. Maybe your model doesn't have field `userprofile`

Comment: Hi @furas, thank you. I do have a 'UserProfile' object in my models file: 
 from django.db import models
#from user_profile.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserProfile(models.Model)`

Comment: put all information in question. it will be more readable and more people will see it - so more people may help you.

Comment: @furas, just did